# windows server 2016 hacked for the third time

Tags: windows, security, firewall, encryption, anti-virus

hello everyone I'm using a windows server 2016 as web server that runs a WebLogic application on a specific port (7001) and I have almost done every thing I know or I read about on the internet to protect  my web server using third party software like Kaspersky ,Spy Hunter ,Firewall issues, autoruns etc.. I'm very confused Kaspersky is always running how it would be stopped and allow the hack tool to encrypt all the data ? for the third time I'm getting hacked and I don't know why ! where is the problem I'm sure 100% its not an inside job ! what should I do , any recommendations ?

[image]

Comment: I would suggest hiring a professional to set it up. If this is the third time clearly what you are doing is not working properly, so an external person could check your setup and see what’s wrong.

Comment: Did you used any USB media? Take into consideration that most of the threads is related to trojans this days, no to network viruses. If it is a part of Active directory it is bad prognosis for other servers state.....

Comment: i have figure it out , the problem is i have checked to keep the temp files within java settings , i have disabled the temp files and